# highchart in popover - bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bootstrap-4

I want to show a highchart inside popover.

here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hfiddle/abpvnys5/47/ of my code.
html:

```
    <ul class="stat_list" style="float: left;">
    <a data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover"
                               data-popover-content="#details"
                               data-placement="bottom" >
   <li>hello</li>
   </a>
   </ul>
   <div id='details' style="display: none">
       <div class="gages"  >
       <div id="test_column_chart" style="height:100px; width:200px" ></div>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="ss" style="">
                                        asdfasdfasdfasdf
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

js:

```
   $(function () {
        get_column_chart(['asdf', 'asdf'], [33, 10],'test');//function for chart
        $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
            html: true,
            content: function () {
                var content = $(this).attr('data-popover-content');
                return $(content).children(".gages").html();
            }
        })
     })
```

when I use bootstrap 3, my code works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/hfiddle/3vr4p9ua/22/

How can I make this work in bootstrap 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for [`sanitize`](http://sanitize) option

> Note that for security reasons the `sanitize`, `sanitizeFn` and `whiteList`
>   options cannot be supplied using data attributes.

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/dy68qeos/1/)